# Chrome opens in a small window

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, window

So I've just installed 1903 windows and everytime I open chrome from the desktop shortcut it opens in a small window, not maximized. Is there any way to fix this?
Changing shortcut properties to start maximized doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

> 1. Press Windows Key + I to open Settings then click System.
> 2. From the left-hand menu select Tablet mode.
> 3. select Use Desktop mode under “When I sign in.”
> 4. Reboot your PC to save changes.

Found [here](https://troubleshooter.xyz/wiki/fix-cant-maximize-programs-from-taskbar/)

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: @Giancarlo sorry to hear that..

Answer (score 0):

The answer that worked for me is from here:
https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B06t29f30M2XM/?hl=en&gpf=%23!msg%2Fchrome%2F6t29f30M2XM%2FxExvZjgmEgAJ&msgid=xExvZjgmEgAJ

Right click on the chrome icon on the desktop, left click on properties,

In the target box should be (assumes chrome on drive C:) "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" <<< remove anything after the closing quote.

After the closing quote add one space then add --start-fullscreen

Now the target line should read "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --start-fullscreen

Click Apply and OK.

Restart Chrome and see if it launches in full screen mode.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Right-click on the shortcut you use for Chrome (whether that's in the taskbar, on the desktop or on your Start menu) and select Properties.
2. Go to the Shortcut tab.
3. Make sure that the Run option is set as 'Maximized'.
4. Click OK.

[Ref article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/all/chrome-opens-in-a-small-window-how-do-i-make-it/4a0059c5-f4b1-421a-a413-19fd5703fa98)